# ampersand(&) and underscore(_) issue in git command line

Tags: windows, git, github, git-bash

I created a repository(private) in github and cloned it to the local machine,pushed stuff and everything was fine. I added a collaborator and he created a branch named `r&d_story` i wanted to work on that branch, so when i tried to clone/pull it to the local machine i am not able to do it because i get an error as follows:

```
$ git pull origin r&d_story

$fatal: couldn't find remote ref r
'd_story' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Searched everywhere regarding the issue no one seems to face it.
can anyone please explain what is wrong?

Comment: Bash is interpreting your `&`, use `\&` or wrap the whole branch name in single quotes.

Comment: Try `git pull origin 'r&d_story'` or `git pull origin r\&d_story`. `&` is a special character.

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay, I will update my answer with the single quotes approach too.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. It was a Windows issue after all, so slightly different. May I suggest that this is not marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape the special character `&`, using this either:

**On Unix (Linux or Mac)**

- `git pull origin r\&d_story`
- `git pull origin 'r&d_story'`

**On Windows**

- `git pull origin "r&d_story"`

Comment: not working same error, any other solutions

Comment: No, that should have worked. I also tested it.

Comment: Did it generate the same error?

Comment: `$git pull origin r\&d_story
    fatal: invalid refspec 'r\'
    'd_story' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Try this one: `git pull origin 'r&d_story'` and tell me if you get the same error.

Comment: `$ git pull origin 'r&d_story'` `fatal: couldn't find remote ref 'r
    'd_story'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191606/discussion-between-heeat-and-jburtondev).

Comment: Turns out the issue was due to using Windows, I have updated my answer accordingly.